# How to add multiple views in the same RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I progress in my app but i have a problem. I can set x TextView in a RelativeLayout with my function `setClassicLabel(JSONArray listLabel)` I call it in my method `onCreate()` and it works well! But i have an other function `setClassicImg(JSONArray listImg)`. I must add imageview in the same Layout where I add labels. I tried to create one RelativeLayout in function `setClassicLabel(JSONArray listLabel)` and one RelativeLayout in the other function who correspond to ImageView. My Json parser works well so i don't need to show the code of it.

Here is my code of my **ClassicView.java** :

```
public ClassicView() {

}
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        JSONParser jParser = null;
        try {
            jParser = new JSONParser("Json.txt");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        content = (Content)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("CONTENT");


         try {
            //this.setClassicLabel(jParser.getContentViewWithId(content.getElemView()).getJSONArray("Label"));
            this.setClassicImg(jParser.getContentViewWithId(content.getElemView()).getJSONArray("Img"));
        //this.setClassicLabel(content.getJSONArray("Label"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setClassicLabel(JSONArray listLabel) throws JSONException {
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        setContentView(rl);

        for (int i = 0; i < listLabel.length(); i++) {  
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (metrics.widthPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_x")), (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_y")));
            params.leftMargin = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_x"));
            params.topMargin = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listLabel.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_y"));
            rl.addView(tv, params);

        }
    }

    public void setClassicImg(JSONArray listImg) throws JSONException {
        RelativeLayout rl2 = new RelativeLayout(this);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        setContentView(rl2);

        for (int i = 0; i < listImg.length(); i++) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
            Log.e("IMG VIEW =", listImg.getJSONObject(i).getString("path"));
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUrl(listImg.getJSONObject(i).getString("path"));
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        /*  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (metrics.widthPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_x")), (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_y")));
            params.leftMargin = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_x"));
            params.topMargin = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_y")); */
            rl2.addView(imgView, paramsImage);
}

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Nothing appears on the screen when i call my method `setClassicImg(JSONArray listImg)` and i don't understand why. I have my url to get my ImageView but i can't see it on my device. There is just an empty RelativeLayout. Somebody have an idea what may i do to put all my elements (labels, imageview) in the same Layout ? May be i make something wrong..

label corresponds to TextView, Img corresponds to ImageView

If you can help me, thank you :)

Comment: Are you missing a closing bracker } for the for-loop in setClassicImg?

Comment: No, the closing bracker is in my code. But i couldn't paste it in my question. It's not the problem

Comment: All your images are going to be placed on top of each other. Shouldn't you specify position for each of them ?

Comment: I tried to specify position. But i don't see the image that i get from the url..

Comment: Did you check the bitmap you've got from URL is not null ? (checking don't cost anything)

Comment: Do you see any exception being thrown ?

Comment: Try settings a local image from the res or asset folder. If that works, it means problem lies in the bitmap logic and not with the layout

Comment: Yes i check the bitmap and the url is good. No exception. My app run and the layout is empty..

Comment: #Guian you're right! My biymap is null, but why ?

Comment: It seems like getBitmapFromUrl() is throwing an exception and returning null. Thats why you have null bitmaps. Check your logcat for confirmation. If its indeed the case then see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the exception but you handle it with e.printStackTrace() only. You are trying to download the image in the UI thread and this throws a system Exception. Move downloading to background thread using `AsyncTask` and make sure your Bitmap is downloaded properly and not returning null.

See [This](http://javatechig.com/android/download-image-using-asynctask-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading images form a URL on main thread. Its going to throw a security exception. Network Operations are not support on main thread in newer versions of android. You should creat an Async task for downloading images.

```
    public synchronized void DownloadTask() {
    task1 = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {

            // download your bitmap here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            assign it to your ImageView here and add it to Relative layout
        }
    }.execute();

}
```